# PDO MariaDB Simple Select

Tags: php, pdo, mariadb

I'm using MariaDB on Fedora 21 and sadly i can insert but i cant select from any table, i think it's rare but it should have a logic explanation

```
$gbd = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=proyecto", "root", "xxx");

$gbd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$ot = $gbd->query("select * from clientes");
```

This is the error I get:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'select * from
>   clientes' at line 1

I run the query at mariab console and it work perfectly. It is a MariaDB bug or is my fault ? (last one probably but its only a select).
I've googled the error but people who also had this problem are using making more complex queries.

After trying with Mariadb I switched to MySQLversion: 5.6.24 MySQL Community Server (GPL).

I tried with mysqli and now queries work, maybe it's a problem with PDO specifically.

**SOLUTION**
I dont understand exactly how but problem dissapear when i deleted database, rebuilt it using SQL script after it failed and showed Error getting DDL for object.
Googled this and used mysql_upgrade -uroot -p --force command now queries work.

Comment: Nothing looks wrong.  However, you probably need to specify a database.